# *.obj file extension is filtered in Joomla 3.x and browser

Tags: joomla-3.x, javascript

It seems that Joomla is set by default to filter the some of the files with different file extensions. Physically the file in question with *.obj(Wavefront) extension exist on server side but I can not find and view it in the Joomla interface when we view under the template manager Details and Files. I confirmed that the file exist on server side with FileZilla.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is: why wavefront file extension is not visible in the Joomla interface as I described, I can not see the loaded file with *.obj extension, all other with *.php, *.html, *.js extensions are fine.

Comment: That makes me think that Joomla is applying the pre-filtering, for the notorious users, for files with diffrerent extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the templates component:

```
$params = JComponentHelper::getParams('com_templates');
$imageTypes = explode(',', $params->get('image_formats'));
$sourceTypes = explode(',', $params->get('source_formats'));
$fontTypes = explode(',', $params->get('font_formats'));
$archiveTypes = explode(',', $params->get('compressed_formats'));
$types = array_merge($imageTypes, $sourceTypes, $fontTypes, $archiveTypes);
if (in_array($ext, $types))
{
$relativePath = str_replace($this->element, '', $dir);
$info = $this->getFile('/' . $relativePath, $value);
$result[] = $info;
}
```

So it only shows files that are in one of its lists of extensions.

You can edit those lists from the template manager options. The options button should be on the top when you open the template manager.